# Forming a matrix that allows columns but not rows [R]

Tags: matrix, statistics, rbind, cbind

I am trying to create a matrix like so:

```
x1 <- rbern(1000,.5)
x2 <- (1-x1)
head(x2)
head(x1)

M <- cbind(x1,x2)
M
```

When I input M, it shows me x1 and x2 as the columns with 1000 rows. I presume this is the matrix. The issue is when I find the transpose

```
A<- t(M)
A
tail(A)
```

It is like x2 disappears, and when I try to multiply A*M, I get the error that these are non comformable arrays.

I have tried this

```
M <- rbind(x1,x2)
M
tail(M)
```

Still, it is like x2 does not exist. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`dim()` allows to see the dimensions, where the first number is the number of rows and the second the numbers of columns, see that in `M` we have 2 columns, `x1` and `x2`, since you used `cbind()`

```
> dim(M)
[1] 1000    2

> dim(A)
[1]    2 1000
```

After transposin `M` to `A` see that you have 2 rows, so `x2` still there, but as the second row.